# documentBuilder: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using DocumentBuilder (of openXML api), to those who doesn't know the documentBuilder I'll give a short explanation: it has a function 'BuildDocument' which gets list of sources (each source contains wmldocument), and string of fileName to save to.

```
    public static void BuildDocument(List<Source> sources, string fileName)
```

the purpose of this function is to build one word docx which contains all the sources. it merges some docs to one.
at the end of its functionality it saves the doc using:

```
    File.WriteAllBytes(...)
```

but when I run my project on the server I keep getting the error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
few times it works ok. and in the visualStudio it also works without errors. 
what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the same stream to open and write to it? (You may need to put more of your code relating to the opening, reading and writing to this file.)

Comment: The issue is probably in where you call the `BuildDocument` method. Is it possible to get that portion of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake, it was in my code and not in the DocumentBuilder.
I wrote:

```
    FileInfo f=new FileInfo....
    f.Create();
```

and I didn't close it. I had to change the code to:
            FileInfo f=new FileInfo....
            FileStream fs=f.Create();
            fs.Close();
Thank you all for your will to help me!!! I realy appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

Probably document file is already open.

Comment: there is: file.close(), of course!!! and I didn't write the code of the buildDocument. I think it something from microsoft

Answer (score 0):

After saving the saving file, check whether it has been **closed** properly. If it is not, then next time when you try to open the file and add text into it, you may get the error. Use something like `File.Close()`

Comment: there is: file.close(), of course!!! and I didn't write the code of the buildDocument. I think it something from microsoft

Comment: Check if there is any permission related issue.